# Define queries that are dependent on multiple contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, content-type, search-results, query

Is it possible to define search queries like this in Sharepoint 2013 on premises:

For all sub-sites which have a list (of content type InfoList) where a particular column in this list has a particular value (Status = Active), search the document archives for documents (of content type Pdoc) with a special tag (where Type of Doc = AAA).

I do not find it obvious how to do this in the query builder. I can get all sites, I can get the lists and I can get the documents. But how can I combine them in a query so that I will get only relevant documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in a single query. You would have to write multiple queries...something like.

1. ContentType=InfoList Status=Active retrieve the Path to the containing Site.
2. ContentType=PDoc DocType=AAA Path=Path from #1

You can do this in JavaScript or and App or C# Code depending on your skill level.